# EF Core Include() statement is null for IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

Ok, so this might be a bit hard to explain without a ton of code to support it but I will try my best.

Essentially I am doing a query (currently on ef core 2.1) with involves a 1 to many relationships. However, the "many" collection is null when it materialized.

Here is the query in question (some code removed for brevity)

```
IQueryable<AccountViewModel> baseQuery = from ms in _managedSupportRepository.GetAllIncluding(m => m.Users) // here is the problem
                                          // a few lines of filters like the one below
                                          where string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientVersionFilter) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ms.ClientVersion) && ms.ClientVersion.Contains(clientVersionFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                          join c in _contractRepository.GetAll() on ms.Id equals c.AssetId into contracts
                                          from c in contracts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                          let isAssigned = c != null
                                          where !isAssignedFilter.valueExists || isAssignedFilter.value == isAssigned
                                          join a in _autotaskAccountRepository.GetAll() on ms.TenantId equals a.Id
                                          where string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountNameFilter) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.AccountName) && a.AccountName.Contains(accountNameFilter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                          select new AccountViewModel
                                          {
                                              AccountName = a.AccountName,
                                              ActiveUsers = ms.GetConsumed(), // here is the problem
                                              ClientVersion = ms.ClientVersion,
                                              ExternalIpAddress = ms.IpAddress,
                                              Hostname = ms.Hostname,
                                              Id = ms.Id,
                                              IsActive = ms.IsActive,
                                              IsAssigned = isAssigned,
                                              LastSeen = ms.CheckInTime,
                                              Status = ms.Status
                                          };

int count = baseQuery.Count();

baseQuery = baseQuery.Paging(sortOrder, start, length);

return (baseQuery.ToList(), count);
```

Just for clarity, the `_managedSupportRepository.GetAllIncluding(m => m.Users)` method is just a wrapper around the `.Include()` method.

So the problem is in the view model for active users `ActiveUsers = ms.GetConsumed(),`. The `GetConsumed()` method is as follows

```
public long GetConsumed()
{
    return Users.Count(u => !u.IsDeleted && u.Enabled && u.UserType == UserType.Active);
}
```

however, this throws a null reference exception because the Users collection is null.
Now my question is, why is the Users collection null when I am explicitly asking it to be loaded?
A workaround at the moment is to alter the queries first line to be this `_managedSupportRepository.GetAllIncluding(m => m.Users).AsEnumerable()` which is just ridiculous as it brings all the records back (which is several thousand) so performance is nonexistent.

The reason it needs to be an IQueryable is so the paging can be applied, thus reducing the amount of information pulled from the database.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this problem:

#### 1) Includes not in the projection don't get included

When you do queries on EF on the provider (server evaluation), you are not -executing- your `new` expressions, so this:

```
ActiveUsers = ms.GetConsumed(),
```

Never actually executes `ms.GetConsumed()`. The expression you pass in for the `new` is parsed and then translated to the query (SQL in case of sql server), but `ms.GetConsumed()` is not executed on the provider (on the query to the database).

So you need to include `Users` on the *expression*. For example:

```
select new AccountViewModel
{
    AccountName = a.AccountName,
    AllUsers = Users.ToList(),
    ActiveUsers = ms.GetConsumed(),
    // etc.
}
```

This way EF knows it needs `Users` for the query and actually includes it (you are not using `Users` in your expression, so EF thinks it doesn't need it even if you `Include()` it... it'll probably show a warning on the `Output` window in Visual Studio), otherwise it tries to project and request only the fields it understands from the `new` expression (which doesn't include `Users`).

So you need to be explicit here... try:

```
ActiveUsers = Users.Count(u => !u.IsDeleted && u.Enabled && u.UserType == UserType.Active);
```

And `Users` will be actually included.

#### 2) Automatic client side evaluation when queries can't get translated

In this case, `Users` will be included because it's in the actual expression... *BUT*, EF still doesn't know how to translate `ms.GetConsumed()` to the provider query, so it'll work (because `Users` will be loaded), but it won't be ran on the database, it'll still be run on memory (it'll will do client side projection). Again, you should see a warning about this in the `Output` window in Visual Studio if you are running it there.

EF Core allows this (EF6 didn't), but you can configure it to throw errors if this happens (queries that get evaluated in memory):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder
        /* etc. */
        .ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
}
```

You can read more about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed explanation! I eventually opted for the more explicit option `ActiveUsers = Users.Count(u => !u.IsDeleted && u.Enabled && u.UserType == UserType.Active);` which worked fine. I guess i was just hoping ef would be smart enough to expand the method call itself, just saves repeating the business logic throughout the application! It's all working now, thanks for your help.